# How to conditionally fire click event on google map in angular

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

In my code I want to have a different action between click and dblclick on my google map in angular. I am wondering how I can do that. I register my listeners like this

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', (event) =>  {
      console.log('We clicked the polygon');
      console.log(polygon);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'dblclick', (event) =>  {
    console.log('We double clicked the polygon');
    console.log(polygon);
  });
```

And it works fine, my only problem is that that before the dblclick event is fired we also fire a click. So my question is what would be the best way to delay the fire of click event for x time to wait for possible dblclick and only fire if we did not fire a dblclick ?

Answer (score -1):

Set a timeout (here 500 ms.) for the click event and cancel it on double click.

```js
function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  let t;

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', (event) => {

    t = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('click');
    }, 500);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', (event) => {
    console.log('double click');
    clearTimeout(t);
  });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

Note that this is not very reliable because :

1. We don't know the exact timeout allowed for a double click event to fire in the API and
2. There seems to be an issue in the sequence in which the `click` and `dblclick` events fire when doing a slower double click. I reported it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183835420).